# Fooling around with the *nix API leads to garbled text files

Tags: c, linux, api, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
        char grade[5];
        char name[30];

        int fd = creat("notas.txt", 0644);

        if (fd == -1) {
            perror("notas.txt");
            return 1;
        }


        while (1) {
            scanf("%s %s", name, grade);
            if (strcmp(name, "end") != 0) {
                write(fd, name, 30);
                write(fd, "\t", 1);
                write(fd, grade, 5);
                write(fd, "\n", 1);
            } else {
                close(fd);
                return 0;
            }
        }

}
```

Hi everyone. I am trying to get into *nix Kernel API programming and I wrote the above program. It reads names and grades from the command line and then writes them to a file. However, the file is garbled, I can only `cat`it (doesn't open with a text editor) and my data appears among a a torrent of garbled random chars. After `cat`ing the file, my prompt also has a bunch of leading random chars like `1C2;1C3`(...).

Why does this happen?

Thank you all.

Comment: ymett answered you. Just wanted to say that instead of `cat` I use `hexdump -C` and when I forget and garble the screen and/or prompt I do a blind `reset<ENTER>` to get screen/prompt back to normal.

Comment: You're not reading names from the command line, but from the standard input. Names on the command line would be passed in the argc, argv parameters of main: int main(int argc, char *argv[]){...};

Comment: @datenwolf, that was just semantics. Sorry.

Comment: @pmg, thanks for sharing those insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`write()` writes bytes to a file, not specifically strings. The third parameter to `write()` is the number of bytes to write. `write(fd, name, 30)` thus writes 30 bytes to the file, but the string in `name` is shorter, so a bunch of random characters which happen to be in memory get written to the file.

In C the length of a string is indicated by putting a nul character (`'\0'`, which is 0) at the end of the string, and can be checked with the `strlen()` function, so you need to write `write(fd, name, strlen(name))`.